# Postgres trigger procedure on insert using data in inserted fields to insert calculated data in another field

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers, insert

Say I have a table `X`, and `X` has fields `X1`, `X2` and `X3`.

I want a solution that whenever I insert values for `X1` and `X2`, `X3` is set automatically to the sum of X1 and X2 with a trigger.

This is something very simple to do in mysql, but after a while on google I cant find a good example of this for postgres, just some info about For each row triggers, but again no examples.

Comment: Show us sample data and expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create the trigger function:

```
create or replace function update_calc_column()
  returns trigger
as
$$
begin
  new.x3 := new.x1 + new.x2;
  return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Create the trigger:

```
create trigger calc_trigger 
   before insert or update on X
   for each row
   execute procedure update_calc_column();
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7ed21/1

The above is essentially a stripped down version of the example in the manual
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE

---

However, storing derived data like that is usually not a good idea. You should simply create a view that returns a column X3 which is defined as `X1 + X2` - a lot less code to maintain and just as efficient (actually it's *more* efficient because you get rid of the trigger overhead).

---

Another (more exotic) option is to use Postgres' object oriented extension and create a virtual column:

```
create or replace function x3(data X) --<< yes, the type of the parameter is the name of the table 
   returns integer
as
$$
   select data.x1 + data.x2;
$$
language sql;
```

You can then use:

```
select x.*, x.x3
from x;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/53acf/1

This however has the disadvantage that you need to *explicitely* select the `x3` column. It will not show up when using `x.*`

Comment: thanks, actually this is for a read heavy application, where reads are an order of magnitude higher than writes, and I will have billions of rows and x will have over a 100 fields, it is for this reason that I want to store sums and averages or some different common use fields because it will make the production of reports faster, it definitely did in mysql, but if theres something i missed about postgres please let me know.

Comment: @user3306481: if you need aggregates and other calculations you should rather look into materialized views.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is just to calculate the `X3` value as a sum of `X1` and `X2` you can use

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable
ADD COLUMN x3 BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (x1 + x2) STORED;
```

A stored generated column is computed when it is written (inserted or updated) and occupies storage as if it were a normal column. So from the performance point of view it is also performant (no calculations are done on `SELECT`).