# Postgres add column with initially calculated values

Tags: postgresql, calculated-columns, alter-table

I'm looking to add a new column to a pre-existing table which is filled with values. The new column is going to be `NOT NULL`, and so for each pre-existing row it will need a value.

I'm looking for the initial values on this column to be calculated based off other values in the table at the time of column creation, and *only* at the time of column creation.

I have a very specific use case, so I'm not looking for a workaround. I'll give a very boiled-down example of what I'm looking for:

Say I have this data:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (
  value1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  value2 INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO numbers(value1, value2) VALUES (10, 20), (2, 5);
```

I wish to create a new column `value3` on the `numbers` table which, at the time of creation, is always equal to the sum of its corresponding `value1` and `value2` columns.

E.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE numbers ADD COLUMN value3 INTEGER;

/* ... some more logic which calculates the initial values ... */

ALTER TABLE numbers
ALTER COLUMN value3 SET NOT NULL;
```

And after this is done, I'd like the following data:

```
-- The 3rd value will be the sum of the first 2 values
SELECT * FROM numbers;

value1 | value2 | value3
-------+--------+-------
10     | 20     | 30
2      | 5      | 7
```

I'll later need to update the data, perhaps ruining the relationship `value3 === (value1 + value2)`:

```
UPDATE numbers SET value3=9823 WHERE value1=10;
```

How can I implement the step of inserting calculated initial values into the `value3` column?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I discovered a simple way! The following adds the `value3` column with the desired initial values:

```
ALTER TABLE numbers
ADD COLUMN value3 INTEGER; -- Exclude the NOT NULL constraint here

UPDATE numbers SET value3=value1+value2; -- Insert data with a regular UPDATE

ALTER TABLE numbers
ALTER COLUMN value3 SET NOT NULL; -- Now set the NOT NULL constraint
```

This method is good when postgres has a native function for the calculation you want to apply to the new column. E.g. in this case the calculation I want is "sum", and postgres does that via the `+` operator. This method will be more complex for operations not natively provided by postgres.

Answer (score -1):

You have two options to do so:

1. If you need the computed value to be stored on database a trigger.

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum_columns()
   RETURNS trigger AS
   $BODY$
   BEGIN
   NEW.value := new.value1+new.value2;
   RETURN NEW;
   END;
   $BODY$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql;

   CREATE TRIGGER calculated_colum AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON numbers
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE sum_columns();
   ```
2. If you don't need the computed value to be stored on database you can use a functional index

   ```
   CREATE INDEX sum_columns_idx ON numbers ((value1+value2));
   ```

Comment: I'm looking for the `value3` column to only be initially calculated when the column is created. I think this will continue to calculate `value3` on insert or update?

Comment: if you want only to calculate it once, never ever calculate again and don't want it to be updated anymore just create the column and make an update or an alter as suggested below.

Comment: For me the example with the trigger as described here did not work, the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37142115/982265) did. Seems to me the major difference is that the trigger should be `BEFORE` insert or update instead of `AFTER`.