# How to check if OLD column exist in Postgres Trigger Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sql-delete

I want to create a deleted logs and insert data from the OLD row column. The problem is the column is not same for each table, some tables only has `transaction_date` and other table only has `created_at`. So I want to check if `transaction_date` just use it, otherwise use `created_at` column. I tried using `coalesce` function but still return:

> ERROR:  record "old" has no field "transaction_date" CONTEXT:  SQL
> statement "INSERT INTO "public"."delete_logs" ("table", "date") VALUES
> (TG_TABLE_NAME, coalesce(OLD.transaction_date,
> coalesce(OLD.created_at, now())))" PL/pgSQL function delete_table()
> line 2 at SQL statement

here is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_table() RETURNS trigger AS
$$BEGIN
INSERT INTO "public"."deleted_logs" ("table", "created_at") VALUES (TG_TABLE_NAME, coalesce(OLD.transaction_date, coalesce(OLD.created_at, now())));

   RETURN OLD;
END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER "testDelete" AFTER DELETE ON "exampletable" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE "delete_table"();
```

Actually, I wanted to create a function for each table, but I think it will be difficult to update the function in the future, so I need to create a single function for all tables.

Comment: `COALESCE` is not going to work on non-existing column it used when an existing column returns `NULL`. You are going to have to check for the existence of the column(s) before you do your `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I want to check if `transaction_date` just use it, otherwise use `created_at` column.

You can avoid the exception you saw by converting the row to json:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_ts_after_delete()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO public.deleted_logs
          (table_name   , created_at)  -- "table" is a reserved word
   VALUES (TG_TABLE_NAME, COALESCE(to_json(OLD)->>'transaction_date', to_json(OLD)->>'created_at')::timestamptz);


   RETURN NULL;  -- not used in AFTER trugger
END
$func$;
```

My answer **assumes that `transaction_date` is defined `NOT NULL`**. Else, the expression defaults to `created_at`. Probably not what you want.

JSON is not as strict as SQL. A reference to a non-existing JSON key results in NULL instead of the exception for the reference to a non-existing table column. So `COALESCE` just works.

Related:

- [How to set value of composite variable field using dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711432/how-to-set-value-of-composite-variable-field-using-dynamic-sql/7782641#7782641)

If the row is wide, it might be cheaper to convert to JSON only once and save it to a variable, or do it in a subquery or CTE.

Related:

- [To convert from Python arrays to PostgreSQL quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533496/to-convert-from-python-arrays-to-postgresql-quickly/31667372#31667372)

If tables never switch the columns in question, passing a parameter in the trigger definition would be *much* cheaper.
You find out (at trigger creation time) *once* with:

```sql
SELECT attname
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'public.exampletable'::regclass
AND    attname IN ('transaction_date', 'created_at')
AND    NOT attisdropped 
ORDER  BY attname DESC
```

This returns 'transaction_date' if such a column exists in the table, else 'created_at', else NULL (no row). Related:

- [PostgreSQL rename a column only if it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68247752/postgresql-rename-a-column-only-if-it-exists/68249810#68249810)

It's still cheapest to have a separate trigger function for each type of trigger. Just two functions instead of one. If the trigger is fired often I would do *that*.

Avoid exception handling if you *can*. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)

> Tip
>
> A block containing an `EXCEPTION` clause is significantly more
> expensive to enter and exit than a block without one. Therefore, don't
> use `EXCEPTION` without need.